# How can I change menu font in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.1

All the fonts in the editor have suddenly become **bold** as you can see in the picture. I don't think it was something I did. Where can I set the font style for this?

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 on an Ubuntu machine if that makes any difference.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to 'File' --> 'Settings' and under 'Appearance & Behavior' to go 'Appearance'. Try forcing a change with the fonts by clicking on the 'Override default fonts by (not recommended):' and choosing a font style & font size. Click 'Ok', see how this changes your font bold issue and perhaps change back.

Comment: That did fix the fonts in the settings window. But the sidebar of the IDE remained the same.

Comment: did manually resetting Android Studio to default settings do the trick?

Comment: No :( Unfortunately that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Excellent +1! Thanks a lot Jaxian

Answer (score 0):

The other way to remedy this situation is to reset all settings back to default. I am running Android Studio in Windows, so I only know how to do this in Windows, but it should be similar in Linux:

Go to your User Folder:
Example: In Windows this would be something like C:\Users\JohnDoe\

Inside that folder there should be another folder called .AndroidStudioBeta or .AndroidStudio (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes it would be hidden).

Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location so you can fix things if something goes wrong).

This should reset your Android Studio settings to the default.